# Calculating Points on a Circle [Java / Processing]

Tags: java, processing, geometry, trigonometry

I need to calculate where the red lines (on the image below) cross the circumference of the circle. The problem is I don't know at what angle (from the center) they will cross the circumference.

The only things I know are the radius of the circle (represented by the blue line) and the x positions of the red lines (each offset by radius/4, represented by the green line).

A mathematical solution of any kind would be appreciated, but bonus points for **Java / Processing**.

[image: Circles and stuff]

Comment: Shouldn't this be migrated to math.stackexchange.com?

Comment: Possibly math.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: Aren't you asking for the definitions of cosinus and sinus functions in the end ?

Comment: Essentially you know 1 side of a right angled triangle (either 1/4 or 1/2 or 3/4 of the radius) and the hypotenuse (=radius), so you can easily do a tan inverse to find the angle.

Comment: it is purely mathematical question, but if ill be you, i would start from finding formula for intersection circle (0,0,r) with line which contains points (i*r/4,0) and (i*r/4,1) for i = {1,2,3,4}. but im not mathematician, maybe there is easier solition

Comment: @MarkSetchell I don't see it, care to elaborate? How is the hypotenus always r

Comment: @arynaq The line from the centre of the circle to the point where the red line crosses the circumference is the radius.

Comment: So it is, 25 years and years and years of math and geometry still gets me. I was looking at the whole thing from the rightside of the circle. Thank you

Comment: Thanks to all who gave me some insight. :)

For those saying this should be in math.stackexchange:
I explicitly mentioned that I want "Java / Processing" code, this is also apparent in my tags, I merely said that a mathematical solution "would be appreciated" as I'd like to learn how the magic behind the functions work.

Answer (score 2):

You know the horizontal value, being the distance from the red line to the center. Let's call that `horz`.

You know the radius already, so you can get the angle as

```
Math.acos(horz / radius)
```

(worked out, not tested)

Answer (score 2):

For normalized coordinates, the computation for the y-coordinate is

```
private static double computeY(double x)
{
    return Math.sin(Math.acos(x));
}
```

"Normalized" means that

- The parameter `x` is a value between 0.0 and 1.0 which be computed from the absolute coordinates by dividing by the radius
- the result, `y`, is a value between 0.0 and 1.0, that can be converted to an absolute coordinates by multiplying with the radius

If you only need the angle, this can simply be computed as `Math.acos(x)`

The result looks like this:

[image]

The code:

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;


public class CircleIntersectionTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.getContentPane().add(new CircleIntersectionPanel());
        f.setSize(500,500);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class CircleIntersectionPanel extends JPanel
    implements MouseMotionListener
{
    private Point mousePosition = null;

    CircleIntersectionPanel()
    {
        addMouseMotionListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics gr)
    {
        super.paintComponent(gr);
        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D)gr;

        double centerX = getWidth() / 2;
        double centerY = getHeight() / 2;
        double radius = 200;

        g.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2));
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);;
        g.draw(new Ellipse2D.Double(
            centerX-radius, centerY-radius, 
            radius+radius, radius+radius));
        if (mousePosition == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.draw(new Line2D.Double(
            mousePosition.x, centerY, mousePosition.x, 0));

        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);

        double x = (mousePosition.x - centerX) / radius;
        double y = computeY(x);

        double cx = centerX + radius * x;
        double cy = centerY - radius * y;
        g.fill(new Ellipse2D.Double(cx-8, cy-8, 16, 16));

        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawString("x = "+x, 10, 30);
        g.drawString("y = "+y, 10, 46);
        g.drawString("angle: "+Math.toDegrees(Math.acos(x)), 10, 62);

    }

    private static double computeY(double x)
    {
        return Math.sin(Math.acos(x));
    }


    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e)
    {
        mousePosition = e.getPoint();
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e)
    {
    }

}
```

Comment: Your solution appears to not use the radius that you pass in?

Comment: @EvanKnowles Thanks, fixed (I had the normalization originally done in the method, but it makes more sense to make it before calling the method)